# solr filtering out and javascript filtering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, solr

when i run solr, I got output like that, but i need show  `"response":{"numFound":4,"start":0,"maxScore":0.21373023,"docs"}` line and all lines have id

this is my html

```
<div id="response">
  <pre class="syntax language-{{lang}} content"><code ng-bind-html="response.data | highlight:lang | unsafe "></code></pre>

 <div id="result">

  <a ng-show="response.data" id="url" class="address-bar addressblock" ng-href="{{url}}">{{hostPortContext}}{{url}}</a>
</div>`
```

this is my query.js that In connection with the result (here "data" is result object)

```
  var url = Query.url(params);

  Query.query(params, function(data) {
    $scope.lang = $scope.query.wt;
    if ($scope.lang == undefined || $scope.lang == '') {
      $scope.lang = "json";

    }
    $scope.response = data ;
    $scope.filterdata=$filter('uppercase') ($scope.response);

    $scope.url = url;


    $scope.hostPortContext = $location.absUrl().substr(0,$location.absUrl().indexOf("#")); 
  });`
```

and got this result

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":21,
    "params":{
      "q":"sed",
      "_":"1580536766390"}},
  "response":{"numFound":4,"start":0,"maxScore":0.21373023,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"/home/sama/sama_installer/masternode",
        "attr_stream_size":["15732"],
        "attr_x_parsed_by":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser"],
        "attr_stream_content_type":["application/octet-stream"],
        "attr_content_encoding":["ISO-8859-1"],
        "attr_resourcename":["/home/sama/sama_installer/masternode"],
        "content_type":"application/x-sh; charset=ISO-8859-1",
        "language":"en",
    ...

        "_version_":1657306606928396288,
        "content":" #!/bin/bash\n#installetion sama project on master\n#cheeke exits sama 
      {

        "id":"/home/sama/sama_installer/start.sh",
        "attr_stream_size":["290"],
        "attr_x_parsed_by":["org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser",
          "org.apache.tika.parser.txt.TXTParser"],
        "attr_stream_content_type":["application/octet-stream"],
        "attr_content_encoding":["ISO-8859-1"],
        "attr_resourcename":["/home/sama/sama_installer/start.sh"],
        "content_type":"application/x-sh; charset=ISO-8859-1",
        "content":" #!/bin/bash\nstart-all.sh\nt=$(cat /var/sama/nodelist)\nfor i in  ,
        "language":"en",
        "content_type_type_s":"application",
        "content_type_subtype_s":"x-sh",
        "url_ss":["start-all.sh",
          "zkServer.sh"],
        "_version_":1657306608004235264}]
  }}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? There doesn't seem to be an actual question in your .. question? Also be aware that you should _not_ expose Solr directly to clients, unless you're very certain about what you're doing. I'm also sceptical about running your `.response` object through an uppercase filter? What are you trying to achieve by doing that? Isn't that the complete response?

Comment: I want filter result so that only show lines that has id & responses. thanks for giving time

Comment: Iterate over `response.docs` instead? That's the actual documents returned from Solr.

Answer (score 0):

I am Assuming data realated to your Question. You Can fetch data in following manner. If it return undefined it means there is not parameter named 'id' else 'id' is present

```js
var data = {
  "responseHeader": {
    "zkConnected": true,
    "status": 0,
    "id": 101,
    "QTime": 21
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 4,
    "start": 0,
    "maxScore": 0.21373023,
    "id": 102
  },
  "response1": {
    "numFound": 4,
    "start": 0,
    "maxScore": 0.21373023
  }
}
console.log(data.response)
console.log(data.responseHeader["id"])
console.log(data.response["id"])
console.log(typeof(data.response1["id"]) == "undefined") //This way you can check if id is present or not.
if (typeof(data.response["id"]) != "undefined") {
  console.log(data.response)
}
```

Comment: tnx for answer but i think wrong in my qustion. in this metod you create data but data in my question is object and created in my code . therefore we dont filtering with your metod. tnx again

Comment: i tryed and it has no result for me

Comment: I want filter result so that only show  lines that has id & responses. thanks for giving time

Comment: i think all lines after "response" are belong of docs and Integrated of one value
are you don't think so that?

Comment: are you doing same code as mentioned in your question

Comment: are you capitalising data object, because I'm not getting error